# Lines are showing up through badge displays on Meta.SE profiles

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, profile-page, internet-explorer

I noticed that there's a small black line through the bronze badge display on my Meta.SE profile, as shown here:

[image]

I've also seen it on [Shog9's profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9). It's on some, but not others.

On [another profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/245360/patrick-hofman), the line shows up under the silver badges:

[image]

This showed up on [another user's profile, too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259867/pizza).

I have yet to see it on the gold badges, but I haven't searched that many profiles.

---

My browser is Internet Explorer, so I don't know if it shows up on other browsers.

Comment: IE explorer? BIN IT BIN IT!!!

Comment: Norepro anyway.

Comment: @nicael I'm not surprised.

Comment: What version of IE? What OS? Are you zoomed in /out?

Comment: @Oded I'm not zoomed in or out. I'm using Internet Explorer 9, and my OS is Windows 7.

Comment: Luckily for you it's not IE6. However the difference is minor.

Comment: A small visual glitch like this (that has no effect on functionality) will not be fixed for an older, unsupported version of the browser.

Comment: @Oded Thanks. I'll probably change browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE 9 is not officlally supported.

See [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) for more information.